# Cómo obtener el apellido de usuario logueado

Tags: php, formularios, php7, login

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener por medio de una variable el apellido del usuario logueado; ya que para loguearse solo solicita: `usuario -> password` pero no apellido, entonces tengo mucha confusión en esa parte.

Lo que trato de hacer es insertar el usuario en donde una tabla tiene el `id_profesor` y esta a su vez guarda el usuario lo cual sería con la session iniciada junto con los apellidos por eso necesito guardarlo en una variable

```
<?php
include("../conecta.php");

session_start();



/* comprobar la conexión */
$nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];
$apellidos=$usuario['apellidos']; 

$nomcomp=$nom ." ".$apellidos;
/* cerrar la conexión */

//Conecto a mi base de datos

//Cadena de consulta que me devuelve todos los registros de la tabla 'users'
$query = "SELECT apellidos FROM registro WHERE usuario='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'";

           
                  //Ejecuto la query para obtener los resultados de la cadena de consulta en la variable $query
                  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)):  
       
                        //la variable $user contiene el contenido de $result en un array asociativo
                        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): 
                        echo $usuario['apellidos']; 

                        


               endwhile; 
       mysqli_free_result($result);
endif;

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */






     if($nom == null || $nom='')
     {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/style.css'>
        <center><br><br><h1><b><font color='#ff8c00'>Usuario no identificado favor de iniciar sesion</font></b></h1><br><br><br><a href='../index.html'><font color='#ff8c00'><h2>Regresar</h2></a></center>";
        die();
     }

     date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $fecha=strftime('%d-%m-%Y',time());
    
    

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
                  <head>
                     <meta charset="utf-8">
                       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=.65, maximun-scale=.65, minimun-scale=.65">
                      <title>DATOS GENERALES</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
           <center>
          <br>
              <img src="../img/logos.png" width="500" height="100" >
               <h3>Datos Generales</h3>
             
                 </center>
<script>
    function TiempoActividad()
    {
    setTimeout("DestruirSesion()",  300000);//Original tiene esté tiempo son 5 minutos
    }
    function DestruirSesion()
    {
    location.href = "../cerrarsesion.php";
    }
</script>
       </head>
       
      
    

<body onload="TiempoActividad()">
    

    <center>
             <form action="validardatos.php" method="post" class="datos" onsubmit="return confirmation()">
                <center>
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr width="50" bgcolor="AECE96">
                        <td width="50">Nombre del Profesor:</td>
                          <td>
                     <?php echo $nomcomp; ?>
                        </td>
                     </tr>   
                  <tr width="50" bgcolor="AECE96">
              <td width="50">Departamento:</td>
         <td>
              <select name="departamento" required="">
                       <option value=""selected="true">Seleccione Un Departamento</option>
                       <option value="Física">Física</option>
                       <option value="Matemáticas">Matemáticas:</option>
                       <option value="Ingeniería y Ciencias Sociales">Ingeniería y Ciencias Sociales:</option>
              </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
          <tr width="50" bgcolor="AECE96">
         <td width="50">     
               Periodo Escolar:
         </td>      
         <td>
              <center><?php echo '2020-2'; ?></center>
         </td>
          <input type="hidden" name="periodo" value="<?php echo '2019-2'; ?>">
          </td>
        </tr> 
         <tr width="50" bgcolor="AECE96">    
         <td width="50">
               Licenciatura / Posgrado
         </td>
            <td>  
             <select name="tipo" required="">
                       
                     <option value="" selected="true">Seleccione un Tipo</option>
                     <option value="Licencitura">Licenciatura</option>
                     <option value="Posgrado">Posgrado</option>
               </select>
           </td>
        </tr>      
          <tr width="50" bgcolor="AECE96">
         <td width="50">  
              Unidad De Aprendizaje
         </td>
         
        
       </table><br>
      

       <input type="submit" class="boton-enviar" value="  Enviar  "/>
       
       
     
       <!--   <input type="submit" class="boton-enviar" value="  Enviar  " onclick="preguntar()"/>-->

           <a href="../index.html"> 
      <input type="button" class="boton-regresar" value="Regresar"></a>

      </center>
 
         </form>
      </center>
              <script type="text/javascript">
     function confirmation() 
     {
        if(confirm("¿Desea Subir La Información?"))
  {
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
     return false;
  }
     }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

pensé en algo como:

`$apellidos=$_SESSION['apellidos'];`

Pero no funcionó.

Comment: Después de que obtienes los datos del usuario puedes asignar a la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['apellidos'] = $usuario['apellidos'];`

Comment: y como traigo la variable

Comment: Dentro del `while`

Comment: puse esto y me aparecio esto --->    $_SESSION['apellidos'] = $usuario['apellidos'];


                        
                              $nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];

                              $nomcomp=$nom ." ".$apellidos;

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: apellidos in C:\xampp\htdocs\group\esfm\profesor\datos.php on line 12

Comment: Si agregas la variable `$_SESSION['apellidos']` antes del `$query` te da ese error.

Comment: y como agrego la variable para mandarla a llamar dentro de un insert

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Podrías explicar con sencillez lo que quieres hacer, olvidándote de cómo lo quieres hacer por el momento? Hablas por ejemplo de un  `INSERT` que no queda reflejado aquí. A veces con el contexto completo se puede optar por soluciones mejores. No entiendo por ejemplo por qué usas variables de sesión ¿?

Comment: no perdon insert no seria solo mostrar el nombre de usuario pero para concatenarlo dentro de una variable

Comment: ¿No lo obtienes dentro del `while`, en esta línea: `echo $usuario['apellidos'];`?

Comment: Amigo, tu error sucede porque en el query tienes comillas dobles dentro de comillas dobles, esto esta mal: `"SELECT apellidos FROM registro WHERE usuario='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'" Debes de ser así, con comillas simple: "SELECT apellidos FROM registro WHERE usuario=.$_SESSION['usuario']."

Comment: @BraylinIvanPayano no, como sugieres no te dará los datos, como la tiene OP está bien, para campos alfanuméricos debes poner comillas simples alrededor, no puedes ponerlo como si fueran números o booleanos.

Answer (score 0):

Había un claro error dentro de la consulta de SQL, y es que estabas haciendo concatenación y en las consultas no se necesitan las concatenación, por favor te pido probar el código y nos deja saber que tipo de error te lanza después. Estaré pendiente a tu respuesta

```
<?php session_start();
include("../conecta.php");


/* comprobar la conexión */
$nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];
$apellidos=$usuario['apellidos']; 

$nomcomp=$nom ." ".$apellidos;
/* cerrar la conexión */

//Conecto a mi base de datos

//Cadena de consulta que me devuelve todos los registros de la tabla 'users'
$query = "SELECT apellidos FROM registro WHERE usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']";

           
                  //Ejecuto la query para obtener los resultados de la cadena de consulta en la variable $query
                  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)):  
       
                        //la variable $user contiene el contenido de $result en un array asociativo
                        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): 
                        echo $usuario['apellidos']; 

                        


               endwhile; 
       mysqli_free_result($result);
endif;

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */






     if($nom == null || $nom='')
     {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/style.css'>
        <center><br><br><h1><b><font color='#ff8c00'>Usuario no identificado favor de iniciar sesion</font></b></h1><br><br><br><a href='../index.html'><font color='#ff8c00'><h2>Regresar</h2></a></center>";
        die();
     }

     date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $fecha=strftime('%d-%m-%Y',time());
    
    

?>
```

Comment: El problema es en esta línea `$apellidos=$usuario['apellidos']; ` está declarada antes de ser asignada, como mencioné en los comentarios la variable debe asignarse dentro del `while`.

Comment: El query con o sin concatenación funciona.